# Is it possible to include ODBC driver when creating an exe file with pyinstaller?

Tags: odbc, pyinstaller, python-3.6, pyodbc

I have made a simple SQL browser and I am trying to make this into an exe file with `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed`. But when I try to run it on another computer which does not have the ODBC driver installed I get an error. Is there some way to include the drivers when building the exe with pyinstaller?